# split/join lists -> E492

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to join a list within a function like this:

```
let mylist=split(globpath(&rtp, 'custompath/*'))
mylist=join(mylist,"\n")
```

But I'm getting:

```
E492: Not an editor command:     mylist=join(mylist,"\n")
```

I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mylist=..` is not a command. You want to **let** the variable, e.g. `let mylist=...`